# Why not transfer the image from the canvas

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert an image from the **canvas** to the **image**, which can be saved by right-clicking mouse.
Everything works fine, but if I put Image on the canvas (drawImage), the image is not transferred.
Image on the left is, and it is not right.
Why?
I also put an example in the sandbox. http://jsfiddle.net/qS9qP/

```
 <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <img src="f2.ico"/>
  </body>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);

var img=new Image();
img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
   }
img.src="http://www.cisco.com/favicon.ico"
// transfer canvas to image
document.images[0].src=document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL("image/png");

</script>
```

Comment: The usefull of this example will become clear if you put in a hidden attribut to tag canvas. We get an image canvas that can be stored right-click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toDataURL` executes before the picture gets loaded. Try putting it in the onload function.

Also, you can not use images from other domains because of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), and it will throw a `SecurityError`:

> Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Now this will work: <kbd>**http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qS9qP/2/show/**</kbd>

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    document.images[0].src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");    //Put it inside
}
img.src = "http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png"                   //Same domain
```

Comment: You are quite right, but I think it's only part of the problem. The other problem is that the browser will probably consider this to be a cross-domain request and `toDataUrl` will throw an exception because of it.

Comment: Thank you all.
You are absolutely right. My mistake was not noticed cross-domain problem
It turns out cross-domain problem occurs even when the open files on the local disk! Then I wanted to make an example of universal and put the link on cisco.com. The main problem of course is that the file does not have time to load. I will be careful.

Answer (score 3):

@Derek and @robertklep are correct:

- the image is drawn after the `toDataURL` call; and then
- `SecurityError: DOM Exception 18`

The cross-domain problem is somewhat beyond the scope of this question, but to demonstrate the point, this can be made to work as you expect (by eliminating the `DOM Exception`):

http://jsfiddle.net/c24w/E3SPv/

Comment: Unfortunately I can not put Accepted answer to both answers. I apologize.

Comment: No problem! @Derek noticed the fundamental problem first :)